# STM32F1 FreeRtos Debug B SVC_Handler

Tags: freertos, stm32f1

i tried to run port FreeRtos V9 to stm32f103 with iar compiler
made project my self.but when debugging , after call vTaskStartScheduler(); microcontroller jump to

```
        PUBWEAK SVC_Handler
    SECTION .text:CODE:REORDER:NOROOT(1)
    SVC_Handler
    B SVC_Handler
```

main.c file link:
[enter link description here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0adlqi7hobv7ply/main.c?dl=0)

what is that for?also FreeRtos doesn't work.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned in **unanswerably incomplete** condition for a year and a half.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the FreeRTOS interrupt handlers.  See #1 on this page of the FreeRTOS FAQ: https://www.freertos.org/FAQHelp.html

Comment: thank you Mr.Richard.added this 3 lines to FreeRTOSConfig.h
`#define vPortSVCHandler SVC_Handler
#define xPortPendSVHandler PendSV_Handler
#define xPortSysTickHandler SysTick_Handler`
bot still jump to SVC_Handler
also call this 3 function before vtaskstart
`xPortSysTickHandler();
  xPortPendSVHandler();
  vPortSVCHandler();`
didnt work